# What is the difference between batch_encode_plus() and encode_plus()

Tags: nlp, transformer, transfer-learning, nlg

I am doing a project using T5 Transformer. I have read documentations related to T5 Transformer model. While using T5Tokenizer I am kind of confused with tokenizing my sentences.

Can someone please help me understand the difference between batch_encode_plus() and encode_plus() and when should I use either of the tokenizers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See also the `huggingface` documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.batch_encode_plus), but as the name suggests `batch_encode_plus` tokenizes a batch of (pairs of) sequences whereas `encode_plus` tokenizes just a single sequence. Looking at the documentation both of these methods are deprecated and you use `__call__` instead, which checks by itself if the inputs are batched or not and calls the correct method ([see the source code with the `is_batched` variable and if statement](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.html#PreTrainedTokenizerBase.__call__)).